# How can I get a component to update on path change while using the same route and component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

When the user is viewing another users profile, and attempt to click their own profile link in the navbar, the component never updates. In both the Redux and React dev tools, it shows that the state has been updated correctly but the component doesnt seem to notice and update.

```
class App extends Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <NavbarFix />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Posts} />
            <Route exact path="/submit" component={AuthRoute(Submit)} />
            <Route exact path="/signup" component={AlreadyAuth(SignUp)} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={AlreadyAuth(LogIn)} />
            <Route exact path="/user/:id" component={AuthRoute(User)} />
            <Route exact path="/item/:id" component={AuthRoute(Item)} />
            <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminAuth(Admin)} />
            <Route exact path="/banned" component={Banned} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

.

```
class User extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      user: [],
      comments: []
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadUser();
  }

  loadUser = () => {
    API.findUserById(this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({
          user: res.data.user,
          posts: res.data.user.Posts,
          comments: res.data.comments
        });
        console.log(this.state)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
      this.setState(this.state)
  }

  handleCommentDelete = id => {
    API.deleteComment(id)
      .then(res => this.loadUser())
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  handlePostDelete = id => {
    API.deletePost(id)
      .then(res => this.loadUser())
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-4 user-data-container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 text-center">
                  <h2>{this.state.user.username}'s Posts</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr className="pb-4" />
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                  {this.state.posts.length > 0 ?
                    this.state.posts.map(post => (
                      <PostContainer handledelete={this.handlePostDelete} post={{ ...post, User: this.state.user }} key={post.id} check={this.props.id} />
                    ))
                    :
                    <h1>No Posts To Show!</h1>
                  }
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-4 user-data-container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 text-center">
                  <h2>{this.state.user.username}'s Comments</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr className="pb-4" />
              <div className="row">
              <div className="col-12">
                {this.state.comments.length > 0 ?
                  this.state.comments.map(comments => (
                      <CommentContainer verified={this.state.user.verified} handledelete={this.handleCommentDelete} check={this.props.id} comment={comments} className="hover-effect single-comment" key={comments.id}/>
                  ))
                  :
                  <h1>No Comments To Show!</h1>
                }
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-4 user-data-container">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12 text-center">
                  <h2>{this.state.user.username}'s Information</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr className="pb-4" />
              <div className="row">
              <div className="col-12">
                  <UserContainer user={this.state.user}/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    username: state.auth.username,
    id: state.auth.id,
    email: state.auth.email,
    profileImg: state.auth.profileImg,
    verified: state.auth.verified
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(User));
```

I believe this has to do with the same route and component being used, so the change isn't actually noticed. Is there any way to fix this? To my understanding, the component should be updating on state change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the link is directing to the same route with just a different param, it will not remount/componentDidMount will not be called again.

So, you could use the componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) lifecycle function and look for newProps.match.params.id and compare it with this.props.match.id and if different call loadUser again.

**You would also need to change your loadUser function to accept an id param

(Param validation not included)

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.loadUser(this.props.match.id);
}

loadUser = (id) => {
  API.findUserById(id)..
  …
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  if(newProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.id) {
     this.loadUser(newProps.match.params.id)
  }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the delayed answer acceptance. Thank you very much!